# FullScreen: TS2769: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2

Tags: reactjs

I use the `FullScreen` component from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-request-fullscreen in my React TS app. This component was working properly for around 1 year. Not so sure if I updated this dependency recently but it keeps coming up with an error of not allowing the `FullScreen` component to have any children. I have also tried including the props `onFullScreenChange` and `onFullScreenError` but still no luck. In my `package.json`, the dependency shows the `FullScreen` version of `^1.1.2` and I checked the official site and this error should not be appearing. Need help thanks.

`The Error:`

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props | Readonly<Props>): FullScreen', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Props>': onFullScreenChange, onFullScreenError
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): FullScreen', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Props>': onFullScreenChange, onFullScreenError

    380 |       <AppStatusContext.Consumer>
    381 |         {(appstatus: AppStatus_) => appstatus && <>
  > 382 |           <FullScreen>
        |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    383 |             <div></div>
    384 |           </FullScreen>
    385 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TkDodo mentioned, the typings are faulty. Since `children` isn't explicitly provided as a propType in the source package's FullScreen.js, you're not allowed to pass children.

The error goes away if you do:

```
<FullScreen onFullScreenChange={(isFullScreen) => console.log(isFullScreen)} 
            onFullScreenError={() => {}} />
```

Notice the `/>` at the end.

If you just did

```
<FullScreen>
</FullScreen>
```

Then react picks up an empty new line node, which causes an error since it gets picked up as a child of FullScreen, but FullScreen isn't allowed to have children.

It seems like all FullScreen does is request fullscreen for the whole document, in which case - could you just do

```
<>
<FullScreen onFullScreenChange={(isFullScreen) => console.log(isFullScreen)} 
            onFullScreenError={() => {}} />
<div>my content here</div>
</>
```

i.e. keep your content **outside** of the FullScreen element. This way it should still allow for FullScreen.

However, if that doesn't work then I'd recommend going to the actual [source](https://github.com/TUBB/react-fullscreen/blob/master/src/FullScreen.js) and cloning its capabilities for your project. It's not a very complicated component to make (perhaps even more cleanly than the source).

Answer (score 1):

The typings provided by this library seem to be faulty. Here is a [TypeScript playground reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFCiSxwBiArgDZsDKulWAdnCIlylPDAC0lAI4ssqCQXZtUPLPzIBuGjUV98wCAICyATwDCJSH34wAFAEo4Abxpw3cSjBZQBt1%204CAHlYObl4BQxCuVX4zAAtkPgBzLABeJwc4VIA%20ZzhcQ1QINiwAOjYIJNsySKUwtT54xJSyRwBfNrha0Ji%20AFEoYih0zJy8gr4ikvLK6qxB6Fa4Duz-APW4QIATYAA3OAB6VY23QIOo%20v5j93stNqA) of your issue.

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/TUBB/react-fullscreen/blob/4ed2bc156941f80f7d0e6be5a7d9531a20d2d0fa/src/index.d.ts#L5-L8), the props defined for this component are missing something like: `children?: React.ReactNode`.

Generally, this doesn't seem like a library I would depend upon. Last code change was 3 years ago, typings are evidently inaccurate, examples use plain js class components etc. [requestFullScreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) is a native browser api that you can use together with refs without a third party library.

Alternatively, you can use something like [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to work around the issue by adding the missing `children` definition in your node_modules. Or, you create a PR to the repo and hope that it gets merged; or, you fork the repo and use your fork instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very informative. But the other answer just gave me the actual solution. Thanks anyways :)